# COPY FROM says data violates unique constraint, but it doesn't

Tags: postgresql

Using the COPY utility to import data into Postgres from a .txt file, and it fails and tells me the 2nd value violates the unique index.  But as you can see, it doesn't.

```
Re: "I'll just sue you. --Steve Jobs

Re: ?I?ll just sue you.? --Steve Jobs
```

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "subject_subject_key"
>   DETAIL:  Key (subject)=(Re: ?I?ll just sue you.? --Steve Jobs) already exists.

How can I get past this and still use COPY FROM (which is handy)?

Comment: You probably already have data in the database?

Comment: No, the table was empty when I tried to load it.  But I looked at the source data, and the ? is a Unicode value I think.  Thanks for the reply.  I'll update if I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If your table was empty, then the mentionned key is repeated in a.txt.

You skipped nex line of error which should tell the line number of second occurance, look example:

```
t=# create table so38(i int,subject text primary key);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy so38 from '/var/lib/pgsql93/a.txt';
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "so38_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (subject)=(Re: ?I?ll just sue you.? --Steve Jobs) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY so38, line 2
t=# \! cat /var/lib/pgsql93/a.txt
1       Re: ?I?ll just sue you.? --Steve Jobs
12      Re: ?I?ll just sue you.? --Steve Jobs
9       Re: "I'll just sue you. --Steve Jobs
```

here

> CONTEXT:  COPY so38, line 2

would help identifying the problem. It does not tell you the line of first occurrence though. To check lines with duplicates, you can use:

```
t=# \! cat -n a.txt | grep 'Re: ?I?ll just sue you.? --Steve Jobs'
     1  1       Re: ?I?ll just sue you.? --Steve Jobs
     2  12      Re: ?I?ll just sue you.? --Steve Jobs
```

here first number is a line number (1 and 2 in my example)